# onPress of children ignored within TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

We are working on an app where a user can read a document, highlight as section and leave a comment.  We've tried a few libraries for text highlighting and ultimately built our own, however most of the npm packages I see follow a similar approach: use a `TextInput` but make uneditable.

We have highlighting working, but the problem is the user needs to be able to see their previous comments by clicking on the section they highlighted. However, `onPress` on the `Text` elements within the `TextInput` don't work.

Here's a trivial example

```
<TextInput>
  <Text onPress={() => console.log('hello')}>Some text</Text>
</TextInput>
```

The `console.log('hello')` will never fire.  How can I keep the `TextInput` from blocking its children's `onPress` events?

And if not, does anyway else know of a way to make text selectable without using an input?

*Note*: I've only tested this on iOS -- I've seen some comments from people saying it works fine for Android

Comment: As I know you can't render any component within `TextInput`.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze You can. I'm currently doing it. The example above works in terms of showing the text.

Comment: Yeah, I checked but as I guess pushing on it triggers `onFocus` event, that's why the log function is canceled.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Do you know of another way for me to have a selectable block of text? Every package I've seen uses `RCTMultilineTextInputView` under the hood, which has this same issue

Comment: Did you try wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor?

Comment: I'm not sure that helps me. I'm not looking to actually edit the text. I want text that I can simply highlight with the native controls for selecting/copying text

Comment: Sorry for the late resp. Did you set `selectable` prop to the Text component?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Yes, but selectable either selects the whole text element or nothing at all. It won't allow me to just a few words in a paragraph

Comment: Also facing this issue. To confirm, we've tested TextInput with children on Android and onPress is not called for the children. However, the library [react native selectable text](https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text) has found a way to use `<Text>` for selectable text on Android (and therefore onPress does work for children). On iOS they use `<TextInput>` for some reason.